# What is the use of Client secrets?

Tags: identityserver4

We are using EntityFramework Core to store configuration data. What is use of store Client secrets along with clients? Or can we add/modify clients secrets later on?

```
 public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
         {
         new Client
        {
        ClientId = "client",

        // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

        // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

        // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
            AccessTokenLifetime=3600
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need the secret to access the [Token Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html) when programmatically requesting tokens.

For example, you can use the [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) library:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
    doc.TokenEndpoint,
    "client_id",
    "secret");

var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("scope");
var token = response.AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Gavin Sutherland's answer explains how to use client secrets, I believe the question is more about why they exist. Basically, think of the client ID and client secret as a username / password enabling a specific client application to initiate OpenID Connect requests (with the other IdentityServer `Client` configuration elements defining which requests are permitted).

You can change secrets, but synchronizing the secret between IdentityServer and the client application is a manual process. (It isn't like certain key rotation scenarios where you can have more than one secret active for awhile, removing the old one after all clients have updated, if that's what you're thinking.)

If you look at any OIDC / OAuth2 third-party identity provider (Google, Facebook, etc.) they all operate by issuing client IDs and secrets associated with specific clients (normally this means specific domains).